# The cmake output, how to make it more verbose?

Tags: c++, windows, macos, cmake, vcpkg

While running cmake 3.21.1 (shipped with Qt online installer) on same project on macOS and Windows I get different output. Why? And how to make it more verbose on Windows?

CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.19.1)

set(CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE ~/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake)

project(MYLIB)

set (CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)

include_directories(~/vcpkg/installed/x64-osx/include)

link_libraries(${OpenCV_LIBS})

set(CMAKE_WINDOWS_EXPORT_ALL_SYMBOLS TRUE)

add_library(mylib SHARED mylib.cpp another_lib.cpp)
```

macOS

```
-- The C compiler identification is AppleClang 12.0.0.12000032
-- The CXX compiler identification is AppleClang 12.0.0.12000032
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/cc - skipped
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/c++ - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Found Protobuf: /Users/user/vcpkg/installed/x64-osx/tools/protobuf/protoc-3.19.4.0 (found version "3.19.4.0") 
-- Looking for pthread.h
-- Looking for pthread.h - found
-- Performing Test CMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD
-- Performing Test CMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD - Success
-- Found Threads: TRUE  
-- Found TIFF: /Users/user/vcpkg/installed/x64-osx/lib/libtiff.a (found version "4.3.0")  
-- Found LibLZMA: /Users/user/vcpkg/installed/x64-osx/lib/liblzma.a (found version "5.2.5") 
-- Found JPEG: /Users/user/vcpkg/installed/x64-osx/lib/libjpeg.a (found version "62") 
-- Found ZLIB: /Users/user/vcpkg/installed/x64-osx/lib/libz.a (found version "1.2.12") 
-- Found OpenCV: /Users/user/vcpkg/installed/x64-osx (found version "4.5.5") 
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /Users/user/mylib/build
```

Windows

```
-- Building for: Visual Studio 16 2019
-- Selecting Windows SDK version 10.0.19041.0 to target Windows 10.0.19044.
-- The C compiler identification is MSVC 19.28.29914.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 19.28.29914.0
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Professional/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.28.29910/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe - skipped
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Professional/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.28.29910/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Found OpenCV: C:/vcpkg/installed/x64-windows (found version "4.5.5")
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: C:/Users/user/mylib/build
```

Comment: What "verbose" you are talking about? If you mean lines like "Found Threads", then they denote searching software. These lines are absent on Windows build because it doesn't need corresponding libraries. (That is, your project needs lesser libraries on Windows than on MacOS).

Comment: The `CMakeLists.txt` file may also do different things on different systems. Have you checked it to see what it really does?

Comment: May I ask what/where should I check?

Comment: @KcFnMi: Normally, lines like "Found XXX" are emitted by `find_package` call with corresponding first argument.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Yes those lines. Why is that my project needs lesser libraries on Windows than on MacOS?

Comment: Probably, these libraries are need for OpenCV itself. E.g. on MacOS you could build OpenCV with `WITH_PROTOBUF` option: https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/db/d05/tutorial_config_reference.html

Comment: It seems to be OpenCV itself which does different things for different platforms. On Windows it might be installed with those extra libraries, so it doesn't need to search for them. Since you're only looking for OpenCV itself, and it's found, there's nothing you need to do.